# Suppress Android Unread Field warning with byte[]

Tags: java, android, arrays, findbugs

I'm using the **`java.lang.SuppressWarnings`** package in Android Studio.

I can't get rid of this one:

```
EI_EXPOSE_REP2: May expose internal representation by incorporating reference to mutable object (findbugs task)
```

It is happening with a setter method.

How to get rid of this warning?

```
 public class PropertyDetailDocumentStorageModel implements Parcelable {
 @SerializedName("picture")
 private byte[] mPicture;    
 public void setmPicture(byte[] mPicture) { this.mPicture = mPicture; }
```

Warning:

```
setmPicture(byte[]) may expose internal representation by storing an externally mutable object into PropertyDetailDocumentStorageModel.mPicture
```

Note this is happening on the only field whose type is `byte[]`. Other fields in the same class which have getters are not throwing this warning.

Comment: Are you trying to suppress the warning, or solve the problem in the code? If it's the latter, we'd need to see your code.

Comment: I want either to find a way to stop the warning with a @Supress... or find a another way to improve the code if there is any?

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, actually it has has a getter : `public byte[] getmPicture() { return mPicture.clone(); }` thanks for pointing me out the bean convention for setter. (`public void setP(T)`) I'll give it a try with Arrays.copyOf(). And last thing you suggest to "suppress the warning", which is exactly what I need help for. What would be the keyword for that warning? @SupressWarning("...?). Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the URF_UNREAD_FIELD applies to the `mPicture` field? Just asking, because the bug type in your description and in the error message differ.

Comment: @Thomas yes... Now after having added :  `public byte[] getmPicture() { return Arrays.copyOf(mPicture, mPicture.length); }` the warning is only on the setter. `EI_EXPOSE_REP2: May expose internal representation by incorporating reference to mutable object`

Comment: So what i would really understand is why am I having this kind of warning on simple getters and setters. Could it be related to the fact that the field is a byte[] type?

Comment: Yes, as I write in my answer below, arrays are always mutable. So yes, it is because you have an array (would be the same for other arrays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So like @Thomas suggested, Arrays are always mutable.
The fix was returning a copy of the property instead of the property itself:

```
public byte[] getmPicture() { return Arrays.copyOf(mPicture, mPicture.length); }

public void setmPicture(final byte[] picture) { this.mPicture = Arrays.copyOf(picture, picture.length); }
```

instead of

```
public byte[] getmPicture() { return mPicture; }

public void setmPicture(byte[] picture) { this.mPicture = picture; }
```

What I didn't know is that for other type like String for example, a simple getter would always return a copy of the object. That is not the case for Arrays.

Answer (score 1):

After clarifying some stuff in the comments, I think the answer is this.

1. URF_UNREAD_FIELD - The field counts as read if a getter exists, because then FindBugs assumes that the field is read from outside the class. If that does not happen, you have some kind of false positive which would require further analysis or suppression.
2. EI_EXPOSE_REP2 - Arrays are always mutable, so by returning the array from the getter you expose it to modification. You could return a copy of the array via `Arrays.copyOf()`, or, again, suppress the warning.

FindBugs warnings are suppressed via the `@SuppressFBWarnings` annotation ([doc](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/annotations/SuppressFBWarnings.html)). You need annotations.jar and jsr305.jar from the FindBugs lib folder on the classpath of the analysis process for FindBugs annotations to work. Example:

```
@SuppressFBWarnings("URF_UNREAD_FIELD")
```

Comment: thanks but, I would have to add an external library to be able to use this solution. And - don't ask why ;) - it is not an option.

Comment: Well, you asked how to suppress FindBugs warnings, and this is how. If you can't change the classpath, and these JARs are not on it, then you cannot suppress FindBugs warnings.

Comment: Sure... But I also can supress the warning by correcting the source of the error. When I published this bug, I didn't know I had to add another library to supress the warning... So your answer definitely helped me!